# WPF animation - transition between 3 styles switched programatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `Card` `UserControl` that represents "one item". I have multiple "items" displayed on a `Grid` with many rows and columns.

`Card` control has 3 possible styles (like states, but I'm not using `UserControl` states, just styles). These styles represent "Selected whole row", "Selected one item" and "Normal" states.

```
<Style x:Key="NormalRowBackground" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="16"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="SelectedRowBackground" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="SelectedCardBackground" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

This is how I switch my styles in code.

```
    private void UpdateSweepView()
    {
        if (!sweepingColumns)
            foreach (CardControl item in currentCardControls)
                if (item.Row == selectedRow)
                    item.Style = (Style)FindResource("SelectedRowBackground");
                else
                    item.Style = (Style)FindResource("NormalRowBackground");
        else
            foreach (CardControl item in currentCardControls)
                if (item.Row == selectedRow && item.Column == selectedCol)
                    item.Style = (Style)FindResource("SelectedCardBackground");
                else if (item.Row == selectedRow && item.Column != selectedCol)
                    item.Style = (Style)FindResource("SelectedRowBackground");
                else item.Style = (Style)FindResource("NormalRowBackground");
    }
```

So far, everything works. Now I want to add some animated transition to this.

My row and card "selection" is controlled programatically (not by mouse or keyboard) and I have no idea how can add animation to this without mouse events like here:

[How to: Animate in a Style at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-in-a-style)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no routed event that fires when the `Style` is being applied but you could handle the `Loaded` event and unload the `UserControl` from the visual tree each time you change the `Style` property, .e.g:

```
<Style x:Key="SelectedRowBackground" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UserControl.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="Green" Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

```
private void UpdateSweepView()
{
    if (!sweepingColumns)
        foreach (CardControl item in currentCardControls)
        {
            if (item.Row == selectedRow)
                item.Style = (Style)FindResource("SelectedRowBackground");
            else
                item.Style = (Style)FindResource("NormalRowBackground");

            grid.Children.Remove(item);
            item.Unloaded += Uc_Unloaded;
        }
    ...

}

private void Uc_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    grid.Children.Add(uc); //this will fire the Loading event and apply the animation
    uc.Unloaded -= Uc_Unloaded;
}
```

This is indeed a workaround. You might be better of applying the animations programmatically without using `Styles`. There is no built-in way to animate the actual application of a `Style` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked example is presenting animations based on `EventTrigger`, but that's not the only way to trigger actions. You can also trigger actions based on `Trigger` or `DataTrigger`:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeStateProperty}" Value="SomeState">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <!-- Animation to be applied when state changes from some other value to "SomeState" -->
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <!-- Animation to be applied when state changes from "SomeState" to some other value -->
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```